# Elseif not returning the proper value on PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

When the user introduces a letter and clicks on submit the script shall return a name that starts with that letter, I wrote it using a Switch/Case structure, now I need to write it using if/elseif/else.

The problem is that no matter what letter I introduce on the Textbox I'll always get the return for A (Aberdefia - Anacleto)

```
$nombrador=$_POST['nombrador'];
$nombrador=strtoupper($nombrador);

if ($nombradorIf = 'A') {
 echo "Aberdefia - Anacleto";
} elseif ($nombradorIf = 'B') {
 echo "Brígida - Brígido";
} else {
echo "Is that even a letter?";
}
```

The code for the letters C to Z is just like the one for A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `==` for **comparison**, `=` is for **assignment**, and `===` is for **identical** or **same type**.

Also, you used `$nombrador` when assigning and `$nombradorIf` when comparing, resulting in an undefined variable.

```
if ($nombrador == 'A') {
    echo "Aberdefia - Anacleto";
} elseif ($nombrador == 'B') {
    echo "Brígida - Brígido";
} else {
    echo "Is that even a letter?";
}
```

Thus, `$nombrador == 'A'` means `$nombrador` is equal to `A`.

And, `$nombrador = 'A'` means to assign `A` to `$nombrador`.

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the **conditional operator** `=` is  **assigning operator**

```
 if ($nombrador == 'A') {
     echo "Aberdefia - Anacleto";
    } elseif ($nombrador == 'B') {
     echo "Brígida - Brígido";
    } else {
    echo "Is that even a letter?";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking conditional statement you have to use `==` (double equal sign) like below:

```
$nombrador=$_POST['nombrador'];
$nombrador=strtoupper($nombrador);

if ($nombrador == 'A') {
 //              ^^ Use like this
 echo "Aberdefia - Anacleto";
} elseif ($nombrador == 'B') {
 //                    ^^ Use like this
 echo "Brígida - Brígido";
} else {
 echo "Is that even a letter?";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but when I give the program a letter it gives me the following error: "Thanks, I've tried both ways, with == and =, but I when I use == I get the following error: " Undefined variable: nombradorIf""

Comment: @AndrésMartínezVargas You have to use your variable which have values like `a`, `b`, etc. i updated my answer. Check it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$nombrador=$_POST['nombrador'];
$nombrador=strtoupper($nombrador);

if ($nombrador == 'A') {
echo "Aberdefia - Anacleto";
} else if($nombrador == 'B') {
echo "Brígida - Brígido";
} else {
echo "Is that even a letter?";
}
```

Your code error near . you condition check variable name is **$nombradorIf** and also not declare variable but You assign the value variable name is `$nombrador` and you not use conditional  operator `==` . so result not proper . You use above the code working fine

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I copy/pasted my variables from a previous project, so I forgot to change them.